# Replacing ng-href with ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I am developing a mobile application and found that angularjs 1.1.4 has a **ngTap** directive available replacing standard **ng-click**. It makes app more robust, so I've decided to replace all my ng-href directive with ng-tap. For this purpose I've created a **"go()**" function available from $rootScope. The problem is that it can not resolve the url variable.

Here's my code.

```
$rootScope.go = function (url) {
    $location.path(url);
}
```

and in template:

```
<a class="niceButtonLikeStyled" data-ng-click="go(/somewhere/var.id/)">{{ var.id }}</a>
```

Using data-ng-click as ngTap is portable and replaces ng-click if new ngMobile loaded.
My problem seems to be with go() argument (mixing static & variable content ?

Maybe there's the other way of just binding new ng-click to all links.. or simply adding own directive that would take value from ng-href and made the location redirect and attach the ng-tap click event.

Comment: need to quote the string being passed to function...`go('/somewhere/var.id/')`

Comment: @charlietfl It doesn't resolve variables then.

Comment: You could do go('/somewhere/'+var.id+'/')

Comment: I've exposed `$location` into `$rootScop`e via app .run() and used `ng-click="$location.path('/url/variable.id/')"`

Answer (score 3):

## AngularJS Expressions for ng-click

When you use [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick), you're calling an AngularJS expression.

Your current code's expression is this:

```
go(/somewhere/var.id/)
```

You need to quote that string:

```
go('/somewhere/' + var.id + '/')
```

## Other Issues

Another issue with your code: The function `go` should be in the scope of the controller rather than in the $rootScope:

```
angular.module('MyModule').controller(
  'MyController',
  function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.go = function (url) {
      $location.path(url);
    }
  }
);
```

Here's how your template would look:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as mycontroller">
  <a class="niceButtonLikeStyled"
     data-ng-click="mycontroller.go('/somewhere/' + var.id + '/')">
    {{ var.id }}
  </a>
</div>
```

That's the biggest issue with the code, you're using $rootScope instead of putting the variables and functions you need in the scope of a controller where it belongs.